# What does the Kobold Geomancer summon "You no take candle!" mean?

Tags: hearthstone

In Hearthstone when a Kobold Geomancer is played the [minon's summon is "You no take candle!"](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Kobold_Geomancer#Quotes). What is being referenced by this exclamation?

Comment: It's something Kobolds say in World of Warcraft.

Comment: yeah but what does it mean?

Comment: Can't believe I only got the Raid Leaders "Handle it!" the other day too

Comment: Wow, I read that and suddenly it makes sense. I never knew he said "Handle it!".

Comment: @IvoCoumans You didn't get it either? That's a 50 DKP minus!

Comment: Playing Hearthstone without having played WoW? Blasphemy!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's a reference to the Kobolds in World of Warcraft, as they only had a single candle, and they were scared you would steal it. It's a statement of defiance, *"You NO TAKE CANDLE!"*

Comment: It refers to the kobold diggers, miners and tunnelers in particular, that have a candle stuck to the top of their head by way of a mining light. http://www.wowhead.com/npc=1236/kobold-digger#screenshots:id=46306 http://www.wowhead.com/item=58903/kobold-candle

Comment: There also is a quest where you ARE taking the candles: http://www.wowhead.com/quest=60/kobold-candles :)

Comment: @RicharddeWit - there's also a quest where one of the reward options is a Kobold's candle.

Comment: This has got to be the simplest, least special answer of my career. And look at all these votes. I'm speechless.

Answer (score 1):

In German mythology Kobolds were spirits that would haunt a home. Wikipedia:
Although usually invisible, a kobold can materialize in the form of an animal, fire, a human being, **and a candle**.

WoW is just paying homage to the mythology of the Kobold - probably to help people realize, before WoW got as big as it did, that the creature was NOT "stolen" from D&D.